# last match with RegEx

Tags: text-processing, grep, regular-expression, pcregrep

I do `grep -oP '(?<=%28).*?(?=%29)' f.txt` on the following line

```
chr01_pilon_pilon   gmap-gsnap  mRNA    55846944    55847057    .   +   .   ID=NbD052382.1.mrna1;Name=NbD052382.1;Note=cytochrome b6/f complex subunit V %28plastid%29  %28NP_054520.1%29;Parent=NbD052382.1.path1;coverage=100.0;identity=100.0;indels=0;matches=114;mismatches=0;unknowns=0
```

and I get `plastid%29  %28NP_054520.1%29`. How is it possible to get the last match only `NP_054520.1`?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the lookbehind with a greedy `\K` ("keep left") assertion:

```
$ grep -oP '.*%28\K.*?(?=%29)' f.txt
NP_054520.1
```